# Why is this program so slow?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

So i came up with this solution to ProjectEuler problem 29 (http://projecteuler.net/problem=29)

The answer is right. I would expect this code to run pretty fast but it runs extremely slowly. I have no idea why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<pair<int,int>> factorized_int; // pairs of base, exponent

factorized_int primeFactors(int n) {
        int primeFactors[100] = {0};
        for (int i=2; i <= n; i++) {
                if (n%i == 0) {
                        primeFactors[i]++;
                        n /= i;
                        i--;
                }
        }

        vector<pair<int,int>> retValue;
        for (int i=2; i<100; i++) {
                if (primeFactors[i] != 0) {
                        retValue.push_back(pair<int,int>(i,primeFactors[i]));
                }
        }

        return retValue;
}

factorized_int pow(factorized_int n, int exponent) {
        factorized_int retValue = factorized_int(n);
        for (size_t i = 0; i<retValue.size(); i++) {
                retValue[i].second *= exponent;
        }
        return retValue;
}

int main() {

        vector<factorized_int> list;

        for (int a=2; a <= 100; a++) {
                factorized_int factorized_a = primeFactors(a);
                cout<<a<<endl;
                for (int b=2; b <= 100; b++) {
                        factorized_int number = pow(factorized_a,b);

                        if (find(list.begin(), list.end(), number) == list.end()) {
                                list.push_back(number);
                        }
                }
        }


        cout<<list.size();
        getchar();
        return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Most of the answers I am getting are in terms of the algorithmic complexity of the algorithm. Notice that n is pretty low (100) and also:

```
int main() {

            vector<factorized_int> list;

            for (int a=2; a <= 100; a++) {
                    factorized_int factorized_a = primeFactors(a);
                    cout<<a<<endl;
                    for (int b=2; b <= 100; b++) {
                            /*factorized_int number = pow(factorized_a,b);

                            if (find(list.begin(), list.end(), number) == list.end()) {
                                    list.push_back(number);
                            }*/
                    }
            }


            cout<<list.size();
            getchar();
            return 0;
    }
```

runs almost instantely. This make me think that the problem is with the constant in the O(n) of the pow function. I think the problem is realted to the various copies of std::vector in the call to pow(factorized_int,int) How could I check and optimize that?

Note: In my PC, the commented version runs in less than 0.1 seconds, and the first one takes more than 30 seconds

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review, and belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.


Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: If a program is slow, the reason is usually that it takes too many counts. Usually, most of them either aren't necessary or can be made on a more effective way.

Think every single steps over.

Comment: In terms of Big O notation calculate the costs. You'll see why it's exponentially slower due to the nested loops, and the recursive nature of the beast.

Comment: @Trollkemada I suggest that you [read a little more about prime number algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Testing_primality_and_integer_factorization).

Comment: the solution on project euler is almost never to brute force it

Comment: @Eiyrioü von Kauyf This solution is not a brute force.

Comment: The sieve of eratosthenes will help

Comment: you should use a `set` instead of a `vector` if you want unique items. The syntax then becomes `set.insert(number)` and you can drop the `if ( find(...) )` condition. Alternatively: just push all values into the vector, then at the end, just sort it and erase duplicates. This _may_ be faster

Comment: Using set REALLY speed up the program. Thanks

Comment: An unordered_set would be a better choice- O(1) compared to O(log(n)).

Comment: I just brute-forced it by doing `pow(a,b)` for all pairs, inserting the values in a `std::set`, and using `set.size()` for the answer. It gives the correct result and only took 0.004 seconds on my PC.

Comment: @Blastfurnace but pow returns a double (or long double) it is difficult (at least for me) to prove that there will not be errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't clear on what 'fast' or 'slow', is, but:

```
int main() {
        vector<factorized_int> list;

        for (int a=2; a <= 100; a++) { //O(a)
                factorized_int factorized_a = primeFactors(a); //O(2a)
                cout<<a<<endl;
                for (int b=2; b <= 100; b++) {  //O(b)
                        factorized_int number = pow(factorized_a,b);//O(2b)

                        if (find(list.begin(), list.end(), number) == list.end()) {
                                list.push_back(number);
                        }
                }//total of O(b*2b) => O(b^2)
        }//total of O(a * (2a + b^2)) => O(n^3)


        cout<<list.size();
        getchar();
        return 0;
}
```

The annotations indicates, roughly, the [algorithmic complexity](http://discrete.gr/complexity/) of your function calls. You have an O(n^3), which is [pretty slow](http://bigocheatsheet.com/).

Comment: And with the amount of the data that this person has to handle, this is REALLY bad.  Good explanation

Comment: absolutely 100% right. +1. In terms of Big O, the nested for loops is costing you a lot.

Comment: @stefan It is idiomatic to use `n` to roll up a diverse set of input variables. Because `a` and `b` aren't directly comparable, but are roughly on the same order, it's fine to use `n` to include both for a rough analysis - which this is.

Comment: @stefan I did include what `n` meant in the answer, but good catch on the math.

Comment: @Trollkemada Cutting out the lowest-order O(n) operation probably doesn't help, especially since you don't indicate what 'fast' and 'slow' means, still. An `O(n^3)` function that runs in 1 second means that an `O(n^4)` will probably take ten seconds. That's the trouble with exponential growth.

Comment: The commented version runs in less than 0.1 seconds, and the first one takes more than 30 seconds.

Comment: By the way it's not `O(a*2a*b^2)`, but `O(a*(2a+b^2))`.

Comment: @stefan Correct! Meaning my first intuition was correct/notation off. It's `O(n^3)`.

Comment: @Trollkemada Given that it's within two orders of magnitude, I'm still chalking this up to algorithmic complexity. You're correct that copying might take much longer, so your `O(b)` factor is larger than your `O(a)` factor, but you're still doing this in a slow manner.